# df.select() or create a temp table then spark.sql("SELECT...")?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If both spark commands do almost the same thing, what should I consider when choosing one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it is just a matter of the style you'd like to work with. Spark will generate a plan for the actual execution either way

One point for SQL is that it is relatively easier to generate if you need that